# sympy Version 1.1.1: 'solve()' containing 'summation()'

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

How would I solve an equation containing a summation expression, i.e.
something like.

[image: Simple Equation]

I would consider the following code fragment to solve this equation:

```
from sympy import *

i, N, x = symbols("n, N, x")
y       = Function("y")
eq      = summation(x + y(i), (i, 0, N)) 

print solve(eq, [x])
```

However, while this equation is simple `solve()` does not produce a result. The 
expected solution would be

[image]

Comment: I edited the question adding the expected result.

Comment: Great minimal example! After 5 years, SymPy still can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the plain answer is that it's just too complicated for the currecnt system to make the substitutions required.

With that said, there might be an issue with expansion of summation here.

I managed to get the correct answer by changing the `Sum`s in the `expand` output with `summation`s, see console session below.

The reason which I believe made the last one possible, is that `summation(x, (i, 0, N))` evaluates to `x*(N + 1)` (effect of the `summation` function), while the `Sum(x, (i, 0, N))` returned by the expansion remains a simple `Sum` object, therefore no substitution made for it after the inner expansion in the `solve` function.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>>
>>> i, N, x, y = symbols("i, N, x, y")
>>> eq         = summation(x + y(i), (i, 0, N))
>>>
>>> expand(eq)
Sum(x, (i, 0, N)) + Sum(y(i), (i, 0, N))
>>>
>>> solve(summation(x, (i, 0, N)) + summation(y(i), (i, 0, N)), x)
[Sum(-y(i), (i, 0, N))/(N + 1)]
```

- By the way, the solution is divided by *N **+ 1***, since the summation contains 0 and N (thus, 0 to N is N + 1 times).

Comment: I think, you hit the point. The `solve()` function does not seem to make the `expand()` step at the current state of development. And, you are right, of course, with the `N+1`.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer I added a last paragraph, `The reason which...`. I believe that's why, and if so it is probably an unintended bug.